# Simple media ingest script

Tags: bash

Trying to script a simple command line tool for ingesting media to a target location following a structured naming convention.

It's functional in its current state but I'd like to know if there are things to improve.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

#make target directory for transfer

make_directory(){

    echo -e "\n\nFollow the prompt to create a project directory.\n\n"
    sleep .5

    while [[ -z "$target_directory" ]]
        do
                echo -e "Path of target directory?"
                read target_directory
        done

    while [[ -z "$brand" ]]
        do
            echo -e "\nBrand Prefix?"
            read brand
        done

    while [[ -z "$project" ]]
        do
            echo -e "\nProject Name?"
            read project
        done

    while [[ -z "$media_type" ]]
        do
            echo -e "\nMedia Type?"
            read media_type
        done

    while [[ -z "$location" ]]
        do
            echo -e "\nLocation?"
            read location
        done

    while [[ -z "$employee" ]]
        do
            echo -e "\nEmployee?"
            read employee
        done

    path=${target_directory}/$(date +'%Y%m%d')_${brand}_${project}_${media_type}_${location}_${employee}

    echo -e "\nCreating directory: ${path}\n\n"

    mkdir -p "${path}"

}

# construct rsync command

construct_rsync(){

    echo -e "\n\nFollow the prompt to construct the rsync command.\n\n"
    while [[ -z "$source_path" ]]
    do
        echo -e "Path to source media?"
        read source_path
    done

    if [[ "$option" == "2" ]]; then
        while [[ -z "$target_directory" ]]
        do
            echo -e "Target directory?"
            read target_directory
        done
    path=$target_directory
    fi

    while true;
    do
        read -p "Additional rsync options? [y/n] " rsync_add
        case $rsync_add in
            [Yy]* )
                echo -e "\nEnter additional rsync parameters:"
                read rsync_options
                break;;
            [Nn]* )
                break;;
            *) echo "Please enter y or no!"
        esac
 done

    echo -e "\nConstructing rsync command...\n"
    sleep .5
    echo -e "Running rsync command:\n
    rsync \n
    -r \n
    --info=progress2 \n
    --log-file=${path}/$(date +'%Y%m%d')_transfer_log.txt \n
    ${rsync_options} \n
    ${source_path}/ \n
    ${path} \n"

    rsync -r --info=progress2 --log-file="${path}/$(date +'%Y%m%d')_transfer_log.txt" ${rsync_options} "${source_path}/" "${path}"
}

# log exit code of rsync

log(){

    echo -e "\nCreating error log..."
    echo $? > "${path}/error_log.txt"

    sleep .5

    if [[ "$?" == "0" ]]; then
        echo -e "\nTransfer complete!"
    elif [[ "$?" != "0" ]]; then
        echo -e "\nError in transfer! Please refer to error_log.txt!"
    fi
}

# read user input and run appropriate functions

while true
do
read -p "Enter [1] to start an ingest or [2] to complete a partial ingest. " option

    case $option in

        1 )
            make_directory
            sleep .5
            construct_rsync
            sleep .5
            log
            break;;
      2 )
            construct_rsync
            sleep .5
            log
            break;;
      * )
            echo "Please enter a valid option!";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I rolled back your last 2 edits. After getting an answer you are not allowed to change your code anymore. This is to ensure that answers do not get invalidated and have to hit a moving target. If you have changed your code you can either post it as an answer (if it would constitute a code review) or ask a new question with your changed code (linking back to this one as reference). Refer to [this post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/120114) for more information

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't familiar with proper etiquette.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is pretty clear and readable. Congratulations!

Here are some suggestions:

1. Stop using `sleep`! Unless this is for a Hollywood hacker movie, it just slows things down. Nobody thinks delays are cool after the first three times you run something.
2. Take command-line arguments instead of prompting for everything. It's a lot easier to just put stuff into a command line than it is to respond to it at the keyboard. Something like:

   ```
   ingest -t $HOME/media -b SONY -p "My Project"
   ```

   There are plenty of [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash#13359121) on how to do this.
3. Add some more functions! Anything you find yourself doing twice should be a function. Also, anything that you have to "break the flow" in order to do should be a function. Here are some examples:

   ```
   while [[ -z "$target_directory" ]]
       do
           echo -e "Path of target directory?"
           read target_directory
       done

   while [[ -z "$brand" ]]
       do
           echo -e "\nBrand Prefix?"
           read brand
       done
   ```

   That's twice! Write a function to do this:

   ```
   target_dir=$(prompt_for_variable target_dir 'Path of target directory?')"
   brand="$(prompt_for_variable brand 'Brand Prefix?')"
   ```

   Now consider this:

   ```
   while true;
   do
       read -p "Additional rsync options? [y/n] " rsync_add
       case $rsync_add in
           [Yy]* )
   ```

   Right in the middle of "construct_rsync" you stop and loop forever prompting the user for a y/n answer. Write a function for that!

   ```
   if get_yn 'Additional rsync options?'
   then
        read -p "Enter the additional options: " rsync_options
   fi
   ```
4. Don't lie to anybody, especially yourself. You have a function called `construct_rsync` but what does it do? It *runs the command.* Either change the name, or change the function.
5. Beware of `$?`. In your `log` function you refer to it several times. But `$?` is updated each time a command is run. So if you're going to make decisions based on the value, you should either capture the value into a separate variable (`status=$?` ... `if $status`) or make a single decision right up front (`if $? ... else ... fi`)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed feedback! 

I don't have much experience with bash or coding in general so it's very helpful to see some better approaches. 

I do not understand how to implement a user prompt function. I believe i'm misunderstanding bash syntax, how arguments are passed, or missing a piece of the problem. If I write a generalized while loop inside a function it does not run properly when using $1 and $2 to populate.

    prompt_user(){
        while [[ -z $input ]]
        do 
        echo "$2"
        read "$1" 
    }

Comment: There's potential problems when mixing `while` loops with user input, because in some circumstances (depending on bash version, also) the body of the `while` loop will execute as a sub-shell (separate process, with its own file handles and stuff). Be sure and check Stack Overflow if you're having trouble.

Comment: I managed to get my original functionality working and it was a combination of misunderstanding the way variables were passed and some syntactical errors causing it to not work on my end.

Appreciate the input!

Answer (score 2):

Consider setting `-e` and `-u` to make the script abort on some common failures, rather than wildly continuing.  The existing script has almost no error checking; as a simple example, closing standard input will lead to an infinite loop repeatedly executing `read`.

Instead of using non-standard `echo -e` to prompt, prefer to supply the prompt as argument to `read`:

```
        read -p "Path of target directory? " target_directory
```

Instead of merely checking that the directory path is a non-empty string with `[[ -z ]]`, we should probably be checking that it's a real directory, with `[ -d ]`.

Output lines should end with newline, and should generally not begin with newline.  And error messages should go to the standard error stream (`>&2`) rather than to standard output.

There are some quotes needed when expanding pathname variables - at present, any filenames including whitespace will be seen as two or more arguments.

Testing `$?` is an antipattern.  This block:

> ```
> sleep .5
>
> if [[ "$?" == "0" ]]; then
>     echo -e "\nTransfer complete!"
> elif [[ "$?" != "0" ]]; then
>     echo -e "\nError in transfer! Please refer to error_log.txt!"
> fi
> ```

can be written much more simply as

```
if sleep .5
then
    echo "Transfer complete!"
else
    echo "Error in transfer! Please refer to error_log.txt!"
fi
```

(though I suspect you actually meant to test the exit code of a different command to the `sleep`).

Finally, run Shellcheck on the code.  I get far too many warnings (some of which I've already identified above):

```
shellcheck -f gcc  216201.sh
216201.sh:7:14: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:7:16: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:7:66: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:7:68: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:13:17: note: read without -r will mangle backslashes. [SC2162]
216201.sh:18:22: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:19:13: note: read without -r will mangle backslashes. [SC2162]
216201.sh:24:22: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:25:13: note: read without -r will mangle backslashes. [SC2162]
216201.sh:30:22: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:31:13: note: read without -r will mangle backslashes. [SC2162]
216201.sh:36:22: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:37:13: note: read without -r will mangle backslashes. [SC2162]
216201.sh:42:22: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:43:13: note: read without -r will mangle backslashes. [SC2162]
216201.sh:48:14: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:48:43: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:48:45: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:58:14: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:58:16: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:58:67: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:58:69: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:62:9: note: read without -r will mangle backslashes. [SC2162]
216201.sh:69:13: note: read without -r will mangle backslashes. [SC2162]
216201.sh:76:9: note: read without -r will mangle backslashes. [SC2162]
216201.sh:79:26: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:80:17: note: read without -r will mangle backslashes. [SC2162]
216201.sh:88:14: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:88:45: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:90:36: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:91:11: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:92:8: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:93:22: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:94:59: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:95:22: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:96:21: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:97:13: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:99:87: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
216201.sh:106:14: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:111:11: note: Check exit code directly with e.g. 'if mycmd;', not indirectly with $?. [SC2181]
216201.sh:112:18: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:113:13: note: Check exit code directly with e.g. 'if mycmd;', not indirectly with $?. [SC2181]
216201.sh:114:18: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
216201.sh:122:1: note: read without -r will mangle backslashes. [SC2162]
```

Comment: Excellent feedback! I've restructured a bit of my code per the two answers i've gotten.

As I understand it, I've set up the mkdir such that it will create the parent directories if they do not exist. 

As to the others, I need flexibility in the naming to accommodate any string I just can't have empty strings.

How do you suggest I check for empty string and re-prompt the user if the input is empty?

I tried to implement a while loop in a function and my inexperience with bash is making progress slow.

Comment: I may have misunderstood from reading the code whether the target directory had to pre-exist; sorry if I got that wrong.  The simple loop seems reasonable to me: `until [ "${dir-}" ]; do read -p "Enter directory: " dir; done` (the `${dir-}` expansion allows `$dir` to be unset without error despite `set -u`).